# How to read input from console,creating console by implementing IConsoleFactory in eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, console, inputstream

I am new to eclipse plugin development.Below is the code i have written for *creating* **Console** by *implementing* **IConsoleFactory** *interface*.Now how should i read input from console.What to code where to code?.I have only one overridden **openConsole** method.

I tried few thing but didn't worked.Help!

```
  public class ConsoleFactory implements IConsoleFactory
     {
        @Override
        public void openConsole() {
           tclConsole = createConsole();
        }


    private void createConsole() {
            IOConsole ioconsole = new IOConsole("Welcome to TclConsole.",null); 
            ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[] {ioconsole});
            ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().showConsoleView(ioconsole);

            IOConsoleOutputStream OPstream = ioconsole.newOutputStream();
    //      System.setOut(new PrintStream(OPstream));
    //      System.setErr(new PrintStream(OPstream));

            IOConsoleInputStream IPstream = ioconsole.getInputStream();
            System.setIn(IPstream);
            return ioconsole;
        }
```

and Xml is as follows:-

```
 <extension
             id="Tclconsole"
             point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleFactories">
          <consoleFactory
                class="com.demo.console.ConsoleFactory"
                label="TclConsole">
          </consoleFactory>
       </extension>
```

For reading input from console may be i can use this code.But where to write it?.I can't write it in openConsole method.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(tclConsole.getInputStream()));
    if(bf.readLine().equals("help"))
    {
       System.out.println("Help : Coming soon");
    }
```